# how i can organize and use reverse in a dictionary python

Tags: python

this is dictionary I don't know how to use sort and reverse.
for some reason don't print the dictionary

```
 disc: {'clave1': ['a','b','c'],
        'clave2': ['ship','car','house'],
        'clave3': [2,1,3]}
```

Comment: What do you want to sort and reverse? The keys ['clave1',....] or lists in the dict values?

Answer (score 1):

I get that the 'disc' is a variable holding the dictionary.
In this case just sort and reverse the values that are lists.

```
disc = {'clave1': ['a','b','c'],
        'clave2': ['ship','car','house'],
        'clave3': [2,1,3]}

for l in disc.values(): 
    l.reverse()
    
for l in disc.values(): 
    l.sort()
```